# property file access using Spring

Tags: spring, properties

I like to access a property file in  a jar. There is foo.jar, which is place in boo.war. In a fooClass class, which inside foo.jar , a variable refer to a properties file place in jar, which was injected using spring.

`<util:properties id="name" location="classpath:\foo-Needed.properties"/>`

When the war  is placed in server and started, `java.lang.NullPointerException` is thorwn while access the properties.

fooClass will be initiated on the server startup.

ANy suggestion to solve this? this might look silly, but I'm new to this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to scan the full classpath, instead of the most direct classpath, you can format the reference to it as such `classpath*:/foo-Needed.properties`.

so, in this case, it would look like

`<util:properties id="name" location="classpath*:/foo-Needed.properties"/>`

Comment: Thanks @incomplete-co.de for your reply, when i try this I'm getting
`Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/classpath*:/foo-Needed.properties]`

Comment: can you please post your web.xml and how you're loading the application context?

Comment: in war the application context are loaded like
    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/service-context.xml"/>

Comment: can you try `classpath*:/META-INF/service-context.xml"`?

Comment: even this throws same exception ! even i tried to place the properties file inside a path, as referred by [Spring](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/resources.html#resources-wildcards-in-path-other-stuff)

Comment: Not sure why **"/"**  append before `classpath*`. This is the exception  Could not open ServletContext resource [/classpath*:com/foo/foo-Needed.properties]

Answer (score 0):

this worked

`<util:properties id="name" location="classpath\*:/foo-Needed.properties"/>`